# Why is Vyatta not saving cluster settings?

Tags: networking, firewall, vyatta

I'm trying to configure an identical pair of devices to run Vyatta and work as a failover cluster. I can configure the clustering just fine through

```
vyatta@firewall# [set clustering configs]
vyatta@firewall# commit
...

vyatta@firewall# save
...
```

The configs all work just fine - I can see the configs by running *show cluster*

```
show cluster 
 dead-interval 5000
 group cluster1 {
     auto-failback false
     monitor [monitor ip]
     primary bender
     secondary flexo
     service [private IP]/16/eth1
     service [public virtual IP]/28/eth0
 }
 interface eth5
 keepalive-interval 2000
 monitor-dead-interval 5000
 pre-shared-secret supersekretpassword
```

on both machines.

*However*, whenever *either* machine reboots, the cluster config gets dropped. It looks like it's loading an old version of the boot config file that doesn't get updated when you run *save*.

Anyone else have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug (Bug 3877 - Cluster configuration does not load if cluster communication interface is down on boot) in the Vyatta software.  If the cluster monitor link is not up at boot time (in your case eth5) it doesn't load the cluster info.  If you look at the actual config.boot file, or issue a load command, you will see it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Still no real clue as to what was causing the problem... I ended up reinstalling Vyatta on both firewalls and re-creating the configs, with cluster configs and conntrack-sync on each device individually. After that, they seemed to work just fine.

I'd love to know what caused it to flip out, though.